# How to setup iOS UI tests as build dependency, like OCUnit?

Tags: xcode, ios, instruments, ocunit

I'd like to add UI tests to an iOS project, in the same manner as OCUnit tests.
I know there is the Instruments + UIAutomation JavaScript approach, but I don't see how that fits into an automated build workflow. Can you setup Instruments + UIAutomation scripts as build dependency for example?

Secondly, I'd rather write the UI tests in the same language as the rest of the code...
Are there any alternatives / things I'm missing?

Thanks.

Martijn

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use OCUnit for UI testing.

If you're already familiar with OCUnit, this piece of code is a good start:
[How to do UI Testing of iOS Applications Using OCUnit](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2828-how-to-do-ui-testing-of-ios-applications-using-ocunit/)

You can then run these tests automatically with `xcodebuild`. It's not straightforward, but worth the extra work. I recommend to take a look at this post: [Xcode4: Running Application Tests From The Command Line in iOS](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/17/xcode4-running-application-tests-from-the-command-line-in-ios/)

UIAutomation can also be automated now with `instruments`, but the fact that you can now run your UI tests with OCUnit makes it less interesting.

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty starting point for a good answer.  I managed to figure this out through brute force and wish I had found this first!  Now, having said that, the problem I have is that I have not been able to find a way to synchronize the UI with OCUnit.  I have to "poll" for the current view or wait MAX time for a RESTful response.  Not ideal, but I could not get a semaphore or other traditional approach to be event-driven.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) by Gorilla Logic. This might be what you are looking for.